# How to detect anomalies in each feature - time series

Tags: time-series, dataset, anomaly-detection, dataframe, anomaly

I have a dataset with 5 features corresponding to 5 sensors that measure each three seconds the state of an accelerator. It is structured as well:

```
Sensor 1 | Sensor 2 | Sensor 3 | Sensor 4 | Sensor 5 | Label
   1.5       1.1        0.8        1.2        1.2       0
   1.2       1.4        1.4        1.4        1.1       0
   1.2       1.1        1.2        1.3        1.5       0
```

The label indicates if the time series is anomaly(=1) or not(=0).
I have an anomaly detection task, and the frameworks I've chosen ([1](https://github.com/khundman/telemanom), [2](https://github.com/NetManAIOps/OmniAnomaly)) give me as output an array with length 3 where I have the labels predicted: (0, 1, 0).
I usually worked with anomaly detection frameworks which gave me a threshold and I could have easily marked the values above it as anomalies.

In this specific case, with this array of length 3, is it right to assume that I could rewrite the following dataset as this? (True = Anomaly, False = normal)

```
Sensor 1 | Sensor 2 | Sensor 3 | Sensor 4 | Sensor 5 |
 False       False      False     False       False    
 True        True       True      True        True    
 False       False      False     False       False
```

So, instead mark one value at time, it directly mark all the time series as anomaly?

Comment: Your labels are all 0 for the shown data. So why would any of the features be considered anomalous?

Comment: That’s an example where the algorithm doesn’t perform well and find an anomaly. What I’m interested to know is if the full row is considered anomalous or not

Comment: Ok, so it is the output of the AD algorithms, not the ground truth. It would normally be called a prediction, to separate from ground truth.

Comment: But for tips on how to better detect anomalies in your dataset, you will need to provide more info on your normal and abnormal data. What kind of data are considered to be anomalies?

Comment: @JonNordby the output I get are the labels, which identify where my anomalies are. In this case, since I got 1 on the second row, would it mean that all the values in that row are anomaly?

Comment: No the entire row is anomalous (the particular *combination* of features values) - the methods shown here does not allow identifying which of the features were anomalous. It can also happen that individual features are all normal - just that their combination is unusual.
PS: Your example does not show 1 on the second row, all rows have 0.

Comment: The 1 I was referring to is the one in the predicted labels. So, if in time-series analysis an algorithm gives an array of labels as output instead of a matrix it means that it calculated the combination of features instead singular values? If yes, isn't my interpretation correct? (the table with true/false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the assumption you've made is incorrect (the whole row being anomalous or not).

To explain this thoroughly, you would need to know which algorithm you're using in order to detect whether or not the final label is `0` or `1`.

For anomaly detection, you can approach the problem as a Supervised (pretty much classification problem), Unsupervised or Semi-Supervised. Assuming from your data, you've chosen the unsupervised approach.

#### Unsupervised Anomaly Detection

An unsupervised anomaly detection has a plethora of algorithm subsets; Distance Based, Statistical, Classification, Angle Based, DBscan, Neural Networks and more. Under those subsets lie algorithms that can help detect anomalous values such as unique NN architectures etc.

Some algorithms (most of the ones I've used) have some form of dimensionality reduction such as PCA. Due to that fact, its a lot more difficult to grasp whether a specific column (e.g `Sensor 1` is anomalous on its own)

A better way to wrap your head around how/why a datapoint is tagged anomalous or not would be to plot a `t-SNE` graph.

If you're interested in me editing my answer to create an anomaly detection model that tags data points as anomaly or not (along with the anomaly score for you to be able to set your personal threshold) and plotting a t-SNE graph, let me know.

Comment: For my task of anomaly detection I need to use a deep learning approach, in particularly the two algorithms I linked in my question. The both give me as output a vector with length=number of samples per features, instead a matrix. I don't understand why and if my interpretation is correct